# Stored procedure filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to write a procedure to retrieve data in which some selection criteria were not taken into procedure if a user not enters a value. I am filtering :

```
WHERE @ts = [ts] or @username = [username] 
or @ip = [ip] or @my_category = [my_category]
or @my_name = [my_name] or @nm1_name = [nm1_name]
or @param = [param] or @short_descr = [short_descr]
```

When I call a stored procedure and when passed one of the parameters that filtering works, and when I write some ,only one filtering work (because I have in my logic 'or'). Replaced by 'and' not satisfied unnecessarily have to pass all the parameters, and I need to transfer only those on which I want to filter out. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Im not sure what your trying to do. Do you mean that you want to do a different filter based on the paramiters passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting your parameters to NULL when you're not using the related filter, right?

So you could use a query like this:

```
WHERE isnull(@ts, [ts]) = [ts]
and isnull(@username, [username]) = [username] 
and isnull(@ip, [ip]) = [ip]
and isnull(@my_category, [my_category]) = [my_category]
and isnull(@my_name, [my_name]) = [my_name]
and isnull(@nm1_name, [nm1_name]) = [nm1_name]
and isnull(@param, [param]) = [param]
and isnull(@short_descr, [short_descr]) = [short_descr]
option (recompile)
```

I advocate using **option (recompile)** in such a scenario

**EDIT:**

with '' instead of NULL

```
WHERE @ts in ('', [ts])
and @username in ('', [username])
and @ip in ('', [ip])
and @my_category in ('', [my_category])
and @my_name in ('', [my_name])
and @nm1_name in ('', [nm1_name])
and @param in ('', [param])
and @short_descr in ('', [short_descr])
```

(more readable than using OR each and every time and it doesn't require recompile*)

(*) as parameters will not be sniffed anyway

Comment: Just to tag onto this, I'd recommend @GeoVIP takes a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html for various methods with a good write up.

Comment: @Serge, thank you for answering but when I filtering like your code its not worked . I execute procedure like : exec myProc '','Tom','','Tom','','','',''

Comment: Well, you could always use NULLIF.   WHERE isnull(nullfi(@ts, ''), [ts]) = [ts].

Comment: @GeoVIP what in my answer made you not choose it as the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Serge thank you for answering , but i dont know how choose 2 answers together , you and Nenad Zivkovic realy help me

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE (@ts IS NULL OR [ts] = @ts)
and (@username IS NULL OR [username] = @username)
and (@ip IS NULL OR [ip] = @ip)
and (@my_category IS NULL OR [my_category] = @my_category)
and (@my_name IS NULL OR [my_name] = @my_name)
and (@nm1_name IS NULL OR [nm1_name] = @nm1_name)
and (@param IS NULL OR [param] = @param)
and (@short_descr IS NULL OR [short_descr] = @short_descr)
```

**EDIT:**

I've seen in comment to other answer that you are passing blank string instead of NULLs. In that case you need to handle them instead (or in addition) to NULLs

```
WHERE (@ts IS NULL OR @ts = '' OR [ts] = @ts)
and (@username IS NULL OR @username  = '' OR [username] = @username)
and (@ip IS NULL OR @ip  = '' OR [ip] = @ip)
and (@my_category IS NULL OR @my_category = '' OR [my_category] = @my_category)
and (@my_name IS NULL OR @my_name = '' OR [my_name] = @my_name)
and (@nm1_name IS NULL OR @nm1_name  = '' OR [nm1_name] = @nm1_name)
and (@param IS NULL OR @param  = '' OR [param] = @param)
and (@short_descr IS NULL OR @short_descr = '' OR [short_descr] = @short_descr)
```

Comment: I have an error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.

Comment: there was a typo, one `IS NULL` was missing for `@ip` - fixed

Comment: In the past I have used `ISNULL(@ts, '') IN ('', [ts])` to do this, functionally the same but is much easier to read when you have more than a couple of conditions to compare.